# Перегрузка математических операторов

Tags: операторы, перегрузка-операторов, c++

Пишу класс для работы с матричной алгеброй. Матрица может быть произвольного размера, поэтому память выделяю в конструкторе (а в деструкторе уничтожаю).
Переопределил оператор +. Возникает проблема при возврате объекта из функции-оператора: деструктор срабатывает раньше, чем вызывающая программа успеет прочитать данные из объекта. Если деструктор убрать - все работает, но память уплывает.
Что я сделал не так? Спасибо.

Вот код:

```
class Matrice{

float ** items;

float & v(uint8_t i, uint8_t j){
    return *(float *)(items + i * w + j);
}

public:

int h, w;

Matrice(uint8_t height, uint8_t width){
    h = width;
    w = width;
    items = (float **)malloc(h * w * sizeof(float));
}

~Matrice(){
    free((void *)items);
}

float * operator[](uint8_t i){
    return (float *)(items + i * w);
}

const Matrice operator +(Matrice M){

    Matrice A(M.h, M.w);

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++){
            A[i][j] = v(i, j) + M[i][j];
        }
    }

    return A;

}
```

};

Comment: К слову,

    const Matrice operator +(Matrice M){

1. Вы возвращаете *новую* матрицу. Зачем делать её *константной* и ограничивать применение метода?
2. Матрицу `M` (аргумент метода) вы используете только для чтения. Зачем использовать передачу аргумента *по значению*? Достаточно дать *константную ссылку*. Будет меньше копирований => меньше выделений/освобождений памяти.
3. Сам метод сложения текущей матрицы с другой матрицей не меняет *текущую* матрицу. Значит, оператор константный.

Итого, замените сигнатуру метода на:

    Matrice operator +(const Matrice& M) const {

Comment: @atwice: Очень правильное замечание.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужен правильный конструктор копирования.

Без него работает автоматически сгенерированный конструктор, который просто копирует указатель на элементы (`items`) из одной матрицы в другую. В результате, когда исходная матрица уничтожается, данные в скопированной матрице становятся недоступны.

Да, и если уж пишете на C++, переходите с `malloc`/`free` на `new[]`/`delete[]`.

Comment: Работает:) Премного благодарен за ответ. Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @lapand: Пожалуйста! Рад, что вы сами знаете, как пишется конструктор копирования.